# JQuery: AJAX error: get data sent to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, query-string

This should be simple, but I can't find info anywhere on how to do it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addToBasket.php',
    data: 'id='+id,
    // ....
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        // how to get the id sent to the server?
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){}
});
```

How can the error handling function access the data sent to the server in the request?

Comment: I am not sure but i guess you can't get sent data in callback as an argument simply because data couldn't be sent to server that's why the request faild after all, i may not be right but its just a gues...

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may help
 make the 'id' which is sent to the server as a global variable and access it

```
var id='bla bla'
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'addToBasket.php',
data: 'id='+id,
// ....
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
    // how to get the id sent to the server?
 alert(id);
},
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){}
});
```

Comment: Thanks - the problem is I have multiple asynchronous requests, and if possible I would rather not have to roll my own way of identifying which request the error came from, if JQuery already has a way of doing it (reinventing the wheel)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `data` property of the ajax options inside the error handler with just `this.data`.
If you don't specifically set the `context` property, `this` inside the callbacks for `$.ajax` will always be the ajax call itself, and then `this.data` will be the serialized string of the data you passed in.

```
$.ajax({
    type  : 'POST',
    url   : 'addToBasket.php',
    data  : 'id='+id,
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        var data = this.data; // "id=something"
    },
    success : function(data, textStatus, xhr){}
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1e82uv4n/)

If you need to parse that string into an object, here's how -> [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

You could also use the global error handler to get the data object, as it the ajax call as it's first argument.
It will fire on all ajax errors, but can be filtered by URL or any other option passed etc.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    if (ajaxSettings.url == 'addToBasket.php') {
        alert(ajaxSettings.data)
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wRPDY/)

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question i have the exact same challenge as Jodes

I found that using this inside the error function holds the ajax object and from that you can extract the data (this.data) although its url encoded

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'addToBasket.php',
data: 'id='+id,
// ....
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
    // how to get the id sent to the server?
    console.log(this.data);
},
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){}
});
```

Hope this helps

edit:
I used https://gist.github.com/brucekirkpatrick/7026682 for unserializing the data string