# Finding failed data and sending again using jquery ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using following script.I am sending some data to php side using ajax and I need to find which all data I send to php have failed and I need to display failed data as html in client side.I am not getting how to find failed data and put all in html by using jquery.(I have 2 input box in html side and keep on adding data to server.Sometimes it may fail.I just want to find failed data and should allow to do ajax again to server)
I find similar issues here [JQuery: AJAX error: get data sent to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041632/jquery-ajax-error-get-data-sent-to-server)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
          $.ajax( {
             url:'/jquery/result',
data:{data1:a,data2:b},
             success:function(data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);
             }
          });
      });
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: and where is the PHP script involved? and make sure that you have the correct `url: ` path

Comment: I use php framework.I am getting success data back from php side and not getting an idea how to retrive every failed data and display in html

Comment: sucess here means ajax query succeeded. failure means it is not able to connect to the file. Ajax failed.

Comment: I am  having similar problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041632/jquery-ajax-error-get-data-sent-to-server

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` has an `error` event which triggers if the ajax call can't access the `url` property (404, 500 errors).

In case you want to verify if the custom data you send to the url fails then you will need some code in your PHP script and `success` event.

eg: let's say you expect `data1` to be an integer. In php

`if(!is_int($_POST['data1])) echo 'Fail'`.

In success event you will verify 
`if(data == 'Fail') /** display error code goes here**/`

Comment: I understand $.ajax has an error event .Let's say I am sending a data to server.(for eg: data1="hello").Does it possible to catch this data if ajax fails ?I am just trying I have sent "hello" to server.But that data failed and returning the text to user

Comment: @aniltc When you look in the network tab of your browser, how does your ajax call fail ? status code 404, 500 or is it not failing (202) ?

Comment: its 404 & 500.Some times my data is not saving from php to database

Comment: I am having similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041632/jquery-ajax-error-get-data-sent-to-server