# On ajax error: how to access posted data

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I'm using .ajaxForm to submit both form data and image files. I have multiple asynchronous calls being made using the same ajaxForm code (most of which do not handle images).

All is fine until ajax encounters an error, at which point I am unable to access any posted data via the error function in order to identify the ajax call that threw the error (in order to correctly handle it with my code).

I was using the [this.data solution suggested by Hammersholt in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041632/jquery-ajax-error-get-data-sent-to-server/26562806#26562806?newreg=26ab9cca7d4c4d08b8b18008a590ec77) which works fine when a fileInput is not used, but fails to retrieve data when a file is selected.

A solution that works using ajaxForm for both data and files would be preferred.

Many thanks for any help with this,

Antony

Comment: check the scope of the posted data .

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the scope of imp_wl_data  is global in this case

```
var imp_wl_data = []
 var imp_wl_ajaxquery = $.ajax(
  {
    url: 'https://myurl',

    async: false,
    success: function(imp_wl_data_res)
    {
      imp_wl_data = JSON.parse(imp_wl_data_res);
    },
  error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
    {
    alert(imp_wl_data);      
    },

  });
```

**Check this**

```
var orderinfo = {
      'ordersplitjson': JSON.stringify(ordersplitjson),
        'customer_id': cust_id,
        'homedelivery': homedelivery,
        'seatnum': seatnum,
        'locationname': location_nam,
        'rownum': rownum
    };
    var json_data = JSON.stringify(orderinfo);
    var ajaxcallquery = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: json_data,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: url + '/orderinsertservice',
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function(response) {


        },
       error: function(jqXHR, exception) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: Is `imp_wl_data` the **POSTED** data?

Comment: Hi, thanks Preethi Jain, though a) I'm not sure that I understand this (as Amit mentioned, is imp_wl_data the posted data?) and b) I really would prefer a solution using .ajaxForm - unless it's easy to switch to from my current code. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay ,  changed the example , here json_data is posted data .

Comment: Thanks, how would I upload a file with this data?